# Setting the size of math font to correspond with text size globally (in the whole document)

Tags: fonts, scale

I have an important question that has been bugging me for a while. I recently got the request that I must write a report in `12pt` (Word standards). Thins is my code before accommodation (just an example, not my real report):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

\[
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 1}^{r} (x_k - \bar{x})^2 f_k = \frac{(x_1 - \bar{x})^2 f_1 + \dots + (x_r - \bar{x})^2 f_r}{N}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the output is very pretty, just as I desired. I happily added
`12pt` to my `\documentclass` and expected a good result. But then, my output turned out to be this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

\[
\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k = 1}^{r} (x_k - \bar{x})^2 f_k = \frac{(x_1 - \bar{x})^2 f_1 + \dots + (x_r - \bar{x})^2 f_r}{N}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is incredibly ugly! The non-math specific symbols (like `x` or `r`) got larger, but not the `\sum` (sigma) symbol as well! I am desperate for help. I know that I can force the `\sum` to become larger with `\mathlarger`, but I don't want to spam this simple command all over my long thesis. **Is there a way to set both math and normal font size (that of non-math specific symbols) to be the same (correspondent) through the whole document?** If you know how to achieve my ambition, please do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\usepackage{exscale}`

Comment: Off-topic: There is no valid reason, and no credible excuse, for loading the `latexsym` package in your LaTeX2e document, especially as you're loading the `amssymb` package anyway. `latexsym` should only be used for documents compiled to LaTeX2.09 standards...

Comment: A separate concern: Because `amsmath` automatically loads `amstext`, `amsbsy`, and `amsopn`, no purpose is served loading these three packages in addition to `amsmath`. While we're on the topic of redundancy: Since `mathtools` automatically loads `amsmath`, there's no need to load `amsmath` either in the preamble of your document.

Comment: To @DavidCarlisle: Thank you, this really worked, I just loaded the package. I can respect your care and humble approach; you could write a whole answer and get many points, but you simply commented, because the thing was so easy. Not many would do the same. All the praise to you, sir.

Comment: To @Mico: I know that many of the packages are redundant, but I have the one `.tex` file in which I load all the major packages (it's kind of a "list", if you will). Every time I work on a real paper, I just pick out some of the packages I want from my "list". If you take a look of my answers I restrained from confusing the ones I helped with the mess that is a plethora of packages.

Comment: @GregorPerčič - What you do in your own documents is *your* business. However, if you post code to a public site such as this one, you really risk doing a huge disservice to future readers of this site by posting highly redundant instructions and loading badly deprecated packages. This risk is especially high if these readers (a) aren't experienced LaTeX users and (b) happen to stumble across your posting via some Google search. Sadly, if they do take your code seriously, they too will start including redundant instructions and loading deprecated packages. *Please* don't teach them bad habits.

Comment: Okay, of course. I agree that I shouldn't post such messy code, not because of my reputation, but because of them.